# spring batch: conditions in processing

Tags: java, spring-batch

I have a spring batch process that should make the following :

i read multiple files named like this:

France.123456

Belgium.569834

France.896471

UK.128956

UK.789632

Belgium.896321

Germany.678900  ...etc

So i have to write all France files contents into one single file called "france" and all germany files contents into one file called "germany" ...etc
So gathering common country files into one.

Here is my batch config class that read all files and generate only one file that contain all contents at once. Which is not the required!!

```
@Component

@Configuration

@EnableBatchProcessing

public class batchConfig {

   private FichierEclate FE =new FichierEclate();

    private String[] fileName;

                @Value("input/*")

                private Resource[] inputResources;

                private String[] Item=new String[100];

                @Autowired

                private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

                @Autowired

                private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

                @Bean

                public FlatFileItemReader<content> reader() {

                               FlatFileItemReader<content> fileItemReader= new FlatFileItemReader<>();

                               fileItemReader.setName("FFIR1");

                               //fileItemReader.setLinesToSkip(1);

                               //fileItemReader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("fichier-eclate-1.csv"));

                               fileItemReader.setLineMapper(lineMappe());

                               return fileItemReader ;
                           }
                @Bean

                public MultiResourceItemReader<content> multiFileReader()  {

                               MultiResourceItemReader<content> multiFileItemReader= new MultiResourceItemReader<>();

                               multiFileItemReader.setResources(inputResources);

                               multiFileItemReader.setName("aaa");

                               multiFileItemReader.setDelegate(reader());

                               return multiFileItemReader ;
                                   }
                @Bean

                public FlatFileItemWriter<content> writer()

                {  FlatFileItemWriter<content> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();

                    writer.setResource(new FileSystemResource("output.csv"));

                               writer.setAppendAllowed(true);

                               writer.setLineAggregator(new DelimitedLineAggregator<content>() {

                                               { //setDelimiter(",");

                                                               setFieldExtractor(new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<content>() {

                                                                               { //setNames(new String[] { "AffaireID","CodeClasse","CodeAppli","NBcompte","NBlot" });

                                                                                     setNames(new String[] {"FileContent"});

                                                                               } });}});

                               writer.setAppendAllowed(true); // pour ajouter du contenu à la fin du fichier au lieu d'écraser l'ancien contenu à chaque fois

                               return writer; }

                @Bean

                public LineMapper<content> lineMappe(){

                               DefaultLineMapper<content> lineMapper= new DefaultLineMapper<>();

                               DelimitedLineTokenizer lineTokenizer=new DelimitedLineTokenizer();

                               //lineTokenizer.setDelimiter(",");

                               lineTokenizer.setStrict(false);

                               lineTokenizer.setNames("FileContent");

                               lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(lineTokenizer);

                               BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper fieldSetMapper=new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper();

                               fieldSetMapper.setTargetType(content.class);

                               lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(fieldSetMapper);

                               return lineMapper; }

                @Bean

                    public Job readCSVFilesJob(Step step1) {

                        return jobBuilderFactory

                                .get("readCSVFilesJob")

                                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())

                                .start(step1)

                                .build(); }

                    @Bean

                    public Step step1(FlatFileItemWriter<content> writer)  {

                        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").<content, content>chunk(2)

                                .reader(multiFileReader())

                                .writer(writer)

                                .build();}}
```

How can i add this condition in my processor ?
Thank you,

Comment: Consider changing your code making it more readable, with less initial space, fewer empty lines and consistent indentation/syntax.

Comment: done, you are right

Comment: Is it required to use Spring Batch for that? Because you can do that with `cat France.* > france` on unix/linux or `type France.* > france` on windows.

Comment: no i need an application to do this automatically to thousands of files :/

Comment: also there will be DB verifications later in the treatment , so it should be a java app and i want to work with batch!! Is this kind of treatment impossible with spring batch?

Comment: It's more readable now. Think about how users will see your post. Most users want to see the code without scrolling, if that is possible (it isn't always though). They could do that if you picked an indentation of only 4 characters. Also, it doesn't seem like there should be any indentation between `private String[] fileName;` and `@Value("input/*")..` as the first is a variable, not the beginning of a method. Presentation isn't everything, but I imagine you're more likely to get interest for your post when the presentation is good :)

Comment: The number of files does not matter, you just need to loop over all countries, but anyway. I recommend you create a job instance per country, meaning you pass all files for each country to a single job instance. This way, you don't need to have a conditional item processor as you can be sure all items coming from the `MultiResourceItemReader` belong to the same country.

Comment: [Example](https://pastebin.com/yTdv2FtK) of presentation.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine your idea seems to be very helpful but can you give me an example how will i read the input files and send specific country files to the MultiResourceItemReader ?

Comment: You can do this by passing an identifying job parameter to your application, for example: `java -jar myjob.jar inputFiles=France.*` for France, `java -jar myjob.jar inputFiles=Belgium.*` for Belgium, etc (create a loop for all countries). Otherwise, you need to write the equivalent code in your main method and programmatically  launch distinct Spring Batch job instances with the corresponding parameters.